# Implement java type with overloaded methods in Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

Is there any way to implement this interface in Nashorn with separate code for both methods?

```
public interface Test {
    void methodA(int a);
    long methodA(long b);
}
```

As something like this will implement both methods:

```
var x = new whatever.Test {
    methodA: function (a) {
        print(a + ", type: " + (typeof a)); // type is number, so I don't even know what method was actually called
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Since JavaScript has no concept of overloaded methods all Java overloads will share the same JavaScript function. If you require different behavior, you'll have to try to differentiate yourself based on the number and types of arguments. If you have

`methodA(Object x)
methodA(Object x, Object y)`

you can have

`function methodA(x, y)`

and you can detect that e.g. `typeof(y) == "undefined"` then the single-arg version was invoked. Alternatively, you can use the `arguments` array throughout.

In your case however, since JavaScript has only one number type and no separate integral types, both int and long become a number (so would float and double and byte and short), so there's not really any way to tell which overload got invoked except maybe testing value ranges.

Comment: There is option to call selected java method from nashorm like `x['methodA(long)'](43)` maybe there is also some way to set handler of that method? or while implementing? 
I will mark this answer as valid in next week unless someone will find a way.